# Adding newly created objects from one list to another in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, email

I have a script that sends an email when a file exceeds a maximum set size.

All of my files come from a XML-file that concludes the path and max size.

The `foreach`that I do to check every size (and to see if it exceeded the max size) looks like:

```
foreach ($item in $list)
{
    if($item.Size -gt $item.TriggerSize -And (Test-Path $item.Path))
    {        
        $body = 
        
        "The file " + $item.Name + " is reaching his max size! 
        <br /><br />  Current size: "+$item.Size.ToString(".00") + " " + $byteSize.Substring(1)  + 
        "<br /> Maximum size: " + $item.MaxSize + " " + $byteSize.Substring(1) 
                
        Send-MailMessage -port 587 -From $from -BodyAsHtml -Encoding $enc -To $to -Subject $subject -Body $body -UseSsl -Credential $credentials
    
    }
}
```

The code is working perfectly, I get an email that looks like:

> The file editix2017.exe is reaching his max size!
>
> Current size:84.93 Mb
>
> Maximum size:100 Mb

The problem I have however is that when I work with more than 1 file, it sends an email for every file that exceeded its max limit.

This means that if I have 2 files that exceeded their max size, it sends 2 seperate emails.

How could I encapsulate every one of the exceeded files in a list and send just one email after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$body +=` to add text to `$body` string each time, then move `Send-MailMessage` outside the loop so it only sends an email after each file has been evaluated:

```
foreach ($item in $list)
{
    if($item.Size -gt $item.TriggerSize -And (Test-Path $item.Path))
    {        
    $body += "The file $($item.Name) is reaching his max size!<br />
    Current size: $($item.Size.ToString(".00")) $($byteSize.Substring(1))<br />
    Maximum size: $($item.MaxSize) $($byteSize.Substring(1))<br /><br />"
    }
}
Send-MailMessage -port 587 -From $from -BodyAsHtml -Encoding $enc -To $to -Subject $subject -Body $body -UseSsl -Credential $credentials
```

edit: I've updated the way `$body` is constructed to use subexpressions `$()` as these return only the properties of the object making your string construction much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

This might do it (untested). It defines $body as an empty string, which we then increment in the loop with the messages about the files and then I have moved the send-mailmessage outside of the loop so that we do it at the end, but only if $body has contents:

```
$body = ""

foreach ($item in $list)
{
    if($item.Size -gt $item.TriggerSize -And (Test-Path $item.Path))
    {        
        $body += 

        "The file " + $item.Name + " is reaching his max size! 
        <br /><br />  Current size: "+$item.Size.ToString(".00") + " " + $byteSize.Substring(1)  + 
        "<br /> Maximum size: " + $item.MaxSize + " " + $byteSize.Substring(1)  + "<br /><br />"

    }
}
If ($body) { Send-MailMessage -port 587 -From $from -BodyAsHtml -Encoding $enc -To $to -Subject $subject -Body $body -UseSsl -Credential $credentials }
```

Comment: Thank you very much